# Numpy array: Function affects original input object as well

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, mutable, numpy-ndarray

I am working at my personal **image augmentation function** in **TensorFlow 2.0**. More specifically, I wrote a function that returns a randomly zoomed image. Its input is `image_batch`, a multidimensional `numpy` array with shape:

```
(no. images, height, width, channel)
```

which in my specific case is:

```
(31, 300, 300, 3)
```

This is the code:

```
def random_zoom(batch, zoom=0.6):
    '''
    Performs random zoom of a batch of images.
    It starts by zero padding the images one by one, then randomly selects
     a subsample of the padded image of the same size of the original.
    The result is a random zoom
    '''

    # Import from TensorFlow 2.0
    from tensorflow.image import resize_with_pad, random_crop

    # save original image height and width
    height = batch.shape[1]
    width = batch.shape[2]

    # Iterate over every image in the batch
    for i in range(len(batch)):
        # zero pad the image, adding 25-percent to each side
        image_distortion = resize_with_pad(batch[i, :,:,:], int(height*(1+zoom)), int(width*(1+zoom)))

        # take a subset of the image randomly
        image_distortion = random_crop(image_distortion, size=[height, width, 3], seed = 1+i*2)

        # put the distorted image back in the batch
        batch[i, :,:,:] = image_distortion.numpy()

    return batch
```

I can then call the function:

```
new_batch = random_zoom(image_batch)
```

At this point, something strange happens: the `new_batch` of images is just as I expected and I'm satisfied with it... but now also `image_batch`, the original input object, has been changed! I don't want that, and I don't understand why that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this line `batch[i, :,:,:] = image_distortion.numpy()` modifies the array that is passed as an argument.

Your confusion likely stems from familiarity with another language such as C++ where objects passed as arguments are implicitly copied.

In Python, what happens is what you might call passing by reference. No copies are made unless you *want* them to be. Therefore, it's not that both `new_batch` and `image_batch` are modified; they are two names pointing to the *same* object that was changed.

Accordingly, you might want to do something like `batch = batch.copy()` at the start of your function.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. However, I have found `np.copy(batch)` in the numpy documentation.

Comment: @Leevo For most intents and purposes, the `copy` method is the same as `np.copy`.